# Best practices to prevent DoS attack, PHP running bash script on apache server

Tags: php, apache, bash

I have a PHP page the sole purpose of which is to spawn a bash script to run some background code (10-15 seconds run time), and then forward to a second page.  The second page waits for the background code to run and displays the output.

Obviously, this set up is fertile ground for a DoS attack.  Can anyone comment on the best practices to prevent such an attack in this situation?  To prevent a non-distributed DoS attack I've considered keeping a log of IP addresses and times for each request and checking each new request against that list.  If <30 seconds from last request, it'll kick out the request.  A distributed DoS attack could be prevented by looking at the number of active spawned processes and kicking out new ones giving a "Server Busy" message, or setting up a queue.

Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: How much legitimate usage do you expect this to get? Is it just one admin user running one job a day on one physical machine, or a utility the general public will have access to?

Comment: Not enough information. **[there are different resources a DDoS can exhaust](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/66580/53736)** and not all of them involve network traffic. Your "workaround" could be nothing more than another attack vector.

Comment: This tool is publicly accessible, yes.  I already have some safeguards in place to prevent network traffic DoS, it is overutilization of server resources that I'm trying to mitigate.